# How can I execute a __doPostBack function in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape a web page that requires clicking on a page button through a __doPostBack function. I have tried the following code in the chrome console.

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$siteContent$widgetLayout$rptWidgets$ctl03$widgetContainer$ctl00$pgrTable$pagingLinksRepeater$ctl02$pageSelector','')
```

This works and I am able to move to the next page. However I am having some difficulty in passing this command to puppeteer. I have tried the following with no success.

```
await page.evaluate(() => { javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$siteContent$widgetLayout$rptWidgets$ctl03$widgetContainer$ctl00$pgrTable$pagingLinksRepeater$ctl02$pageSelector','');})
```

I have also tried to modify the aspnet form by resetting the __EVENTTARGET value to

```
'ctl00$siteContent$widgetLayout$rptWidgets$ctl03$widgetContainer$ctl00$pgrTable$pagingLinksRepeater$ctl02$pageSelector'
```

but it does not seem to be sufficient. Grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: `javascript:__doPostBack(`  This is a way of executing javascript from a link,  your already in javascript land with `page.evalulate`, so have you tried just doing `__doPostBack(`

Comment: tried. but it says __doPostBack is not a recognized function.

Comment: Just click the button, how about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ASP.NET is registering two `__doPostBack` functions.

One in the page:

```
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
```

And another one in the source script

```js
Sys.Extended.UI.ControlBase.__doPostBack = function(n, t) {
    if (!Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack())
        for (var i = 0; i < Sys.Extended.UI.ControlBase.onsubmitCollection.length; i++)
            Sys.Extended.UI.ControlBase.onsubmitCollection[i]();
    Function.createDelegate(window, Sys.Extended.UI.ControlBase.__doPostBackSaved)(n, t)
};
```

As they are extending `window` with `ControlBase` the `__doPostBack` function you are getting is the one from the resource file instead of the one from the page.

You can click the button instead.

```js
await page.click('#ctl00_siteContent_widgetLayout_rptWidgets_ctl03_widgetContainer_ctl00_pgrTable_pagingLinksRepeater_ctl01_pageSelector');
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much and also for the extended explanation. It works :)

Answer (score 0):

You may call the function before it is defined in the page. Try to wait for it to be defined:

```js
await page.waitForFunction(() => typeof __doPostBack !== 'undefined');
await page.evaluate(() => {
  __doPostBack('ctl00$siteContent$widgetLayout$rptWidgets$ctl03$widgetContainer$ctl00$pgrTable$pagingLinksRepeater$ctl02$pageSelector','');
});
```

Comment: thank you @vsemozhetbyt for the suggestion. Though I am still getting an evaluation error ...

Answer (score 0):

Came across this post after I tried doing this same thing with the website
https://members.acacamps.org/rentals

I tried to use `page.click` on the "Next" button with the navigator at the bottom, but I get a `Node not found or not an HTML element` error.

Not sure why Puppeteer doesn't pick it up, but imagine it has to do with the `doPostBack`.

The solution was to use document.querySelector:

`page.evaluate(()=>document.querySelector('linkid').click())` worked

Hope this might help anyone that had this issue as well. I think we need to use `querySelector` here because this case does not have two separate doPostBack calls like the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

For people trying to find a solution when the **link is NOT already in the page**, you can insert it in the innerHTML (or replace a already existing link) and than click it.